# Can't do dataframe show() or use sql :Zeppelin

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin

I'm getting a dependency issue every time I do a spark/pyspark df.show() and if I run an sql query in their respective interpreters in Zeppelin (0.9.0). This is the error that I get,

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.getByteArrayRdd(SparkPlan.scala:247)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeTake(SparkPlan.scala:339)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.CollectLimitExec.executeCollect(limit.scala:38)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.org$apache$spark$sql$Dataset$$collectFromPlan(Dataset.scala:3389)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$head$1.apply(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset$$anonfun$52.apply(Dataset.scala:3370)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$$anonfun$withNewExecutionId$1.apply(SQLExecution.scala:80)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withSQLConfPropagated(SQLExecution.scala:127)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:75)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.withAction(Dataset.scala:3369)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.head(Dataset.scala:2550)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.take(Dataset.scala:2764)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.getRows(Dataset.scala:254)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.showString(Dataset.scala:291)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:751)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:710)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset.show(Dataset.scala:719)
  ... 45 elided
```

I looked into this here and tried all changes that were asked to be made in the previously asked questions regarding the same issue.

Here are the list of things that I tried:

1. excluding jackson-databind jar in spark interpreter
2. deleting jackson-databind jar from zeppelin lib
3. deleting jackson-databind, jackson-annotations and jackson-core jars from zeppelin lib
4. replacing the jar with the conflicting version in spark and vise-versa
5. Tried changing the versions of spark - 2.4.0, 2.4.4, 2.4.5
6. Build the project from source

I still couldn't resolve this issue. Does anyone have an idea regarding how to go about this?

Comment: Does your code work in a spark shell?

Comment: @cronoik Yes the code works in spark shell